# Send Whatsapp message from browser (web.whatsapp.com) to people not yet in my contact list?

Tags: whatsapp

My smartphone is not by me, but it's charging and well connected to Internet, anyhow I am using whatsapp through [web.whatsapp.com](http://web.whatsapp.com) at the moment.

The real problem is I urgently need to contact specifically OVER WHATSAPP some new people that are not between my contacts, whose phone numbers I DO have with me (calling them or another type of communication is not an option).

Already tried adding them to my synchronized contacts, but the phone doesn't seem to be updating the contacts list as it should, or whatsapp doesn't synchronizes the new contacts to it's own internal list, therefore they never appear as option to be contacted.

I believe Whatsapp Web should have an option but there's neither an option to start a new conversation with non-existent contacts, nor to add a new contact to the smartphones contacts, nor to the inner whatsapp contacts list.

Has anyone a solution to contact this people over Whatsapp from my same whatsapp number?

Comment: The web version doesn't give you more options. If anything it gives less and requires you to have the phone online at the same time. I don't understand what you're trying to get specifically from the whatsapp web and I'm afraid whatever that is, it's off-topic here.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I believe it's clear I'm trying to do some job done (coordinating a production process, replacing someone who was responsible of it but isn't available today, at the exact moment I don't have my smartphone with me). I don't understand why would this be off-topic. Anyways, I believe I've found a smart solution, I'm already trying it.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks, ok, I've already checked that link and [this one also](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Everything seems to be fine with my question. I can even tell you I've found 2 very good answers [in Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-send-WhatsApp-messages-to-someone-not-on-your-contact-list). I'm currently writing a detailed answer for this question with the best solution there was for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using the official "Click to Chat" API

The current API URL procedure now comes in a shorter format and also allows including the text message (very nice!):

```
https://wa.me/NUMBER/?text=MESSAGE
```

(where `NUMBER` is a full phone number in international format [only numbers, no spaces or symbols] and `MESSAGE` is the URL-encoded pre-filled message)

It's also possible to assign a message to be sent with no user being specified, allowing to send the same message to many people at once (just perfect for what I needed to do at this moment). It works like this:

```
https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext
```

Anyone can simply copy, modify and visit this URLS to get the contact being made.

The complete official and current information is in here:
https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/

(Nice job Whatsapp!)

### Using another native App

Another possible solution for this situation could have been using an app called [WhatsDirect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cycloneworld.whatsdirect), but haven't tried it, rather prefer a solution with no new apps needed.

Answer (score 1):

We'll you can do it the same way we do it with [mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-programmatically-whatsapp)

```
 web.open('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone='+phone_no+'&text='+message)
```

This will prepopulate the text for given mobile number(Enter the phone_no as CountryCode and the number eg +918888888888)
Then using **pyautogui** you can press enter onto whatsapp.web

I've taken this from this repository - [Github repo](https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/awesomepy/blob/master/program.py)